# How to properly set up a backup file

Tags: mysql

Apologies if the title is confusing i wasn't too sure what else to call this question. Basically What I've accomplished so far is I've created a backup of a table ORDER_DETAIL and made the modifications to it so that when it runs the original data from table ORDER_DETAIL is inserted into a table ag715. The purpose of this is that when a separate script is ran called HACKER, this script changes ORDER_DETAIL.

My Task now is to compare the tables and show whats been deleted, inserted and updated. However my issue is when i run my backup file, ORDER_DETAIL is empty and ag715 has data so I'm unable to compare the tables.

My question is if my backup file was modified properly, or if its incorrect and deletes the contents of a table ORDER_DETAIL when ran?

```
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.13, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost  Database: csit115
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   8.0.13

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
 SET NAMES utf8mb4 ;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;

--
-- Table structure for table `ORDER_DETAIL`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ORDER_DETAIL`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client   = @@character_set_client */;
 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 ;
CREATE TABLE `ORDER_DETAIL` (
  `ORDER_ID` decimal(9,0) NOT NULL,
  `PRODUCT_NAME` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `UNIT_PRICE` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `QUANTITY` decimal(9,0) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `DISCOUNT` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ORDER_ID`,`PRODUCT_NAME`),
  KEY `FK_PRODUCT_NAME_ag715` (`PRODUCT_NAME`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_ORDER_ID_ag715` FOREIGN KEY (`ORDER_ID`) REFERENCES `ORDERS` (`order_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_PRODUCT_NAME_ag715` FOREIGN KEY (`PRODUCT_NAME`) REFERENCES `PRODUCT` (`product_name`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `ORDER_DETAIL`
--

LOCK TABLES `ag715` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `ag715` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `ag715` VALUES (248,'Mozzarella di Giovanni',34.80,5,0.00),(248,'Queso Cabrales',14.00,12,0.00),(248,'Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee',9.80,10,0.00),(249,'Manjimup Dried Apples',42.40,40,0.00),(249,'Tofu',18.60,9,0.00),(250,'Jack\'s New England Clam Chowder',7.70,10,0.00),(250,'Louisiana Fiery Hot Pepper Sauce',16.80,15,0.15),(250,'Manjimup Dried Apples',42.40,35,0.15),(251,'Gustaf\'s Knackebrod',16.80,6,0.05),(251,'Louisiana Fiery Hot Pepper Sauce',16.80,20,0.00),(251,'Ravioli Angelo',15.60,15,0.05),(252,'Camembert Pierrot',27.20,40,0.00),(252,'Geitost',2.00,25,0.05),(252,'Sir Rodney\'s Marmalade',64.80,40,0.05),(253,'Gorgonzola Telino',10.00,20,0.00),(253,'Inlagd Sill',14.40,42,0.00),(253,'Maxilaku',16.00,40,0.00),(254,'Guarana Fantastica',3.60,15,0.15),(254,'Longlife Tofu',8.00,21,0.00),(254,'Pate chinois',19.20,21,0.15),(255,'Chang',15.20,20,0.00),(255,'Inlagd Sill',15.20,25,0.00),(255,'Pavlova',13.90,35,0.00),(255,'Raclette Courdavault',44.00,30,0.00),(256,'Original Frankfurter grune Sosse',10.40,12,0.00),(256,'Perth Pasties',26.20,15,0.00),(257,'Inlagd Sill',14.40,6,0.00),(257,'Original Frankfurter grune Sosse',10.40,15,0.00),(257,'Schoggi Schokolade',35.10,25,0.00),(258,'Chang',15.20,50,0.20),(258,'Chef Anton\'s Gumbo Mix',17.00,65,0.20),(258,'Mascarpone Fabioli',25.60,6,0.20),(259,'Gravad lax',20.80,1,0.00),(259,'Sir Rodney\'s Scones',8.00,10,0.00),(260,'Jack\'s New England Clam Chowder',7.70,16,0.25),(260,'Outback Lager',12.00,21,0.25),(260,'Ravioli Angelo',15.60,50,0.00),(260,'Tarte au sucre',39.40,15,0.25),(261,'Sir Rodney\'s Scones',8.00,20,0.00),(261,'Steeleye Stout',14.40,20,0.00),(262,'Chef Anton\'s Gumbo Mix',17.00,12,0.20),(262,'Gnocchi di nonna Alice',30.40,2,0.00),(262,'Guarana Fantastica',17.00,15,0.00),(263,'Guarana Fantastica',3.60,28,0.00),(263,'Longlife Tofu',8.00,36,0.25),(263,'Nord-Ost Matjeshering',20.70,60,0.25),(263,'Pavlova',13.90,60,0.25),(264,'Chang',15.20,35,0.00),(264,'Jack\'s New England Clam Chowder',7.70,25,0.15),(265,'Alice Mutton',31.20,30,0.00),(265,'Outback Lager',12.00,20,0.00),(266,'Queso Manchego La Pastora',30.40,12,0.05),(267,'Boston Crab Meat',14.70,50,0.00),(267,'Lakkalikoori',14.40,15,0.15),(267,'Raclette Courdavault',44.00,70,0.15),(268,'Mozzarella di Giovanni',27.80,4,0.00),(268,'Thuringer Rostbratwurst',99.00,10,0.00),(269,'Geitost',2.00,60,0.05),(269,'Mozzarella di Giovanni',27.80,20,0.05),(270,'Inlagd Sill',15.20,30,0.00),(270,'Ipoh Coffee',36.80,25,0.00),(271,'Geitost',2.00,24,0.00),(272,'Gorgonzola Telino',10.00,40,0.00),(272,'Mozzarella di Giovanni',27.80,24,0.00),(272,'Sir Rodney\'s Marmalade',64.80,6,0.00),(273,'Boston Crab Meat',14.70,60,0.05),(273,'Geitost',2.00,20,0.00),(273,'Gorgonzola Telino',10.00,15,0.05),(273,'Ikura',24.80,24,0.05),(273,'Lakkalikoori',14.40,33,0.05),(274,'Flotemysost',17.20,20,0.00),(274,'Mozzarella di Giovanni',27.80,7,0.00),(275,'Guarana Fantastica',3.60,12,0.05),(275,'Raclette Courdavault',44.00,6,0.05),(276,'Ikura',24.80,15,0.00),(276,'Konbu',4.80,10,0.00),(277,'Rossle Sauerkraut',36.40,20,0.00),(277,'Tarte au sucre',39.40,12,0.00),(278,'Gula Malacca',15.50,16,0.00),(278,'Raclette Courdavault',44.00,15,0.00),(278,'Rod Kaviar',12.00,25,0.00),(278,'Vegie-spread',35.10,8,0.00),(279,'Alice Mutton',31.20,15,0.25),(280,'Guarana Fantastica',3.60,12,0.00),(280,'Pate chinois',19.20,20,0.00),(280,'Rhonbrau Klosterbier',6.20,30,0.00),(281,'Guarana Fantastica',3.60,6,0.00),(281,'Steeleye Stout',14.40,4,0.00),(281,'Teatime Chocolate Biscuits',7.30,1,0.00),(288,'Scottish Longbreads',10.00,3,0.10),(288,'Tourtiere',5.90,10,0.10),(289,'Aniseed Syrup',8.00,30,0.00),(289,'Wimmers gute Semmelknodel',26.60,9,0.00),(290,'Chef Anton\'s Gumbo Mix',17.00,20,0.00),(290,'Maxilaku',16.00,15,0.00),(290,'Original Frankfurter grune Sosse',10.40,10,0.00),(290,'Thuringer Rostbratwurst',99.00,15,0.00),(291,'Gula Malacca',15.50,24,0.10),(291,'Konbu',4.80,20,0.10),(291,'Manjimup Dried Apples',42.40,2,0.10),(292,'Sir Rodney\'s Marmalade',64.80,20,0.00),(293,'Carnarvon Tigers',50.00,12,0.00),(293,'Guarana Fantastica',3.60,10,0.00),(293,'Rhonbrau Klosterbier',6.20,6,0.00),(293,'Vegie-spread',35.10,5,0.00),(294,'Alice Mutton',31.20,15,0.00),(294,'Camembert Pierrot',27.20,21,0.00),(294,'Chai',14.40,18,0.00),(294,'Ipoh Coffee',36.80,15,0.00),(294,'Rhonbrau Klosterbier',6.20,6,0.00),(295,'Gnocchi di nonna Alice',30.40,4,0.00),(296,'Gudbrandsdalsost',28.80,15,0.00),(296,'Pavlova',13.90,30,0.00),(296,'Queso Cabrales',16.80,12,0.00),(297,'Inlagd Sill',14.40,60,0.00),(297,'Mozzarella di Giovanni',27.80,20,0.00),(298,'Chang',15.20,40,0.00),(298,'Inlagd Sill',15.20,40,0.25),(298,'Raclette Courdavault',44.00,30,0.25),(298,'Tarte au sucre',39.40,15,0.00),(299,'Outback Lager',12.00,20,0.00),(299,'Teatime Chocolate Biscuits',7.30,15,0.00),(300,'Louisiana Hot Spiced Okra',13.60,30,0.00),(300,'Scottish Longbreads',10.00,20,0.00),(301,'Boston Crab Meat',14.70,10,0.00),(301,'Gnocchi di nonna Alice',30.40,20,0.00),(302,'Alice Mutton',31.20,40,0.00),(302,'Ipoh Coffee',36.80,12,0.00),(302,'Rossle Sauerkraut',36.40,28,0.00),(303,'Boston Crab Meat',14.70,40,0.10),(303,'Louisiana Fiery Hot Pepper Sauce',16.80,30,0.10),(303,'Scottish Longbreads',10.00,15,0.10),(304,'Flotemysost',17.20,2,0.00),(304,'Maxilaku',16.00,30,0.00),(304,'Raclette Courdavault',44.00,10,0.00),(305,'Carnarvon Tigers',50.00,25,0.10),(305,'Inlagd Sill',14.40,30,0.10),(305,'Thuringer Rostbratwurst',99.00,25,0.10),(306,'Nord-Ost Matjeshering',20.70,10,0.00),(306,'Perth Pasties',26.20,10,0.00),(306,'Tourtiere',5.90,5,0.00),(307,'Scottish Longbreads',10.00,3,0.00),(307,'Tarte au sucre',39.40,10,0.00),(308,'Gudbrandsdalsost',28.80,1,0.00),(308,'Outback Lager',12.00,5,0.00),(309,'Chef Anton\'s Cajun Seasoning',17.60,20,0.00),(309,'Flotemysost',17.20,3,0.00),(309,'Grandma\'s Boysenberry Spread',20.00,30,0.00),(309,'Ipoh Coffee',36.80,20,0.00),(309,'Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee',11.20,2,0.00),(310,'Pavlova',13.90,10,0.00),(310,'Tarte au sucre',39.40,5,0.00),(311,'Gudbrandsdalsost',28.80,7,0.00),(311,'Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee',11.20,6,0.00),(312,'Ipoh Coffee',36.80,24,0.00),(312,'Perth Pasties',26.20,20,0.00),(312,'Rhonbrau Klosterbier',6.20,10,0.00),(312,'Rossle Sauerkraut',36.40,4,0.00),(313,'Inlagd Sill',15.20,12,0.00),(314,'Escargots de Bourgogne',10.60,30,0.10),(314,'Mascarpone Fabioli',25.60,40,0.10),(314,'Tarte au sucre',39.40,25,0.10),(315,'Outback Lager',12.00,30,0.00),(315,'Sasquatch Ale',11.20,14,0.00),(316,'Jack\'s New England Clam Chowder',7.70,10,0.00),(316,'Tarte au sucre',39.40,70,0.00),(317,'Chai',14.40,20,0.00),(318,'Jack\'s New England Clam Chowder',7.70,15,0.00),(318,'Lakkalikoori',14.40,6,0.00),(319,'Alice Mutton',31.20,8,0.00),(319,'Lakkalikoori',14.40,30,0.00),(319,'Rossle Sauerkraut',36.40,14,0.00),(320,'Flotemysost',17.20,30,0.00),(321,'Steeleye Stout',14.40,10,0.00),(322,'Filo Mix',5.60,15,0.00),(323,'Genen Shouyu',12.40,5,0.00),(323,'Grandma\'s Boysenberry Spread',11.20,4,0.00),(323,'Inlagd Sill',14.40,4,0.00),(324,'Pavlova',13.90,21,0.15),(324,'Raclette Courdavault',44.00,40,0.15),(324,'Spegesild',9.60,30,0.00),(324,'Steeleye Stout',14.40,70,0.15),(324,'Vegie-spread',35.10,80,0.15),(325,'Gorgonzola Telino',10.00,4,0.00),(325,'Grandma\'s Boysenberry Spread',25.30,6,0.00),(325,'Konbu',4.80,12,0.00),(325,'Mozzarella di Giovanni',27.80,40,0.00),(325,'Tofu',18.60,9,0.00),(326,'Chef Anton\'s Cajun Seasoning',17.60,24,0.00),(326,'Ravioli Angelo',15.60,16,0.00),(326,'Rhonbrau Klosterbier',6.20,50,0.00),(327,'Chang',15.20,25,0.20),(327,'Escargots de Bourgogne',10.60,30,0.20),(327,'Nord-Ost Matjeshering',20.70,35,0.20),(327,'Queso Cabrales',16.80,50,0.20),(328,'Louisiana Fiery Hot Pepper Sauce',16.80,40,0.00),(328,'Raclette Courdavault',44.00,9,0.00),(328,'Scottish Longbreads',10.00,10,0.00),(329,'Côte de Blaye',210.80,20,0.05),(329,'Gnocchi di nonna Alice',30.40,12,0.05),(329,'Nord-Ost Matjeshering',20.70,8,0.05),(329,'Teatime Chocolate Biscuits',7.30,10,0.05),(330,'Gumbar Gummibarchen',24.90,50,0.15),(330,'Mozzarella di Giovanni',27.80,25,0.15),(331,'Tourtiere',5.90,15,0.00),(332,'Carnarvon Tigers',50.00,40,0.20),(332,'Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee',11.20,10,0.20),(332,'Zaanse koeken',7.60,16,0.20),(333,'Flotemysost',17.20,40,0.10),(333,'Sir Rodney\'s Scones',8.00,10,0.10),(333,'Tofu',18.60,10,0.00),(334,'Filo Mix',5.60,8,0.00),(334,'Scottish Longbreads',10.00,10,0.00),(335,'Chang',15.20,7,0.20),(335,'Gorgonzola Telino',10.00,25,0.20),(335,'Manjimup Dried Apples',42.40,48,0.20),(335,'Mascarpone Fabioli',25.60,6,0.20),(336,'Chef Anton\'s Cajun Seasoning',17.60,18,0.10),(337,'Gravad lax',20.80,28,0.00),(337,'Gumbar Gummibarchen',24.90,24,0.00),(337,'Inlagd Sill',15.20,20,0.00),(337,'Mozzarella di Giovanni',27.80,25,0.00),(337,'Tunnbrod',7.20,40,0.00),(338,'Alice Mutton',31.20,20,0.00),(338,'Uncle Bob\'s Organic Dried Pears',20.70,15,0.00),(339,'Alice Mutton',31.20,70,0.05),(339,'Chef Anton\'s Cajun Seasoning',17.60,10,0.00),(339,'Tarte au sucre',39.40,28,0.00),(340,'Carnarvon Tigers',50.00,20,0.05),(340,'Ipoh Coffee',36.80,40,0.05),(340,'Jack\'s New England Clam Chowder',7.70,12,0.05),(341,'Geitost',2.00,8,0.00),(341,'Raclette Courdavault',44.00,9,0.15),(342,'Chang',15.20,24,0.20),(342,'Gorgonzola Telino',10.00,56,0.20),(343,'Pavlova',13.90,16,0.00),(343,'Queso Manchego La Pastora',30.40,15,0.00),(343,'Wimmers gute Semmelknodel',26.60,6,0.00),(344,'Longlife Tofu',8.00,30,0.00),(345,'Chang',15.20,45,0.15),(345,'Pavlova',13.90,49,0.15),(345,'Sirop d\'erable',22.80,90,0.15),(345,'Thuringer Rostbratwurst',99.00,24,0.15),(346,'Louisiana Hot Spiced Okra',13.60,60,0.00),(346,'Queso Cabrales',16.80,30,0.00),(346,'Schoggi Schokolade',35.10,50,0.00),(346,'Tourtiere',5.90,80,0.00),(347,'Queso Cabrales',16.80,6,0.20),(348,'Alice Mutton',31.20,10,0.00),(348,'Rossle Sauerkraut',36.40,12,0.00),(349,'Gumbar Gummibarchen',24.90,15,0.00),(349,'Steeleye Stout',14.40,8,0.00),(350,'Guarana Fantastica',3.60,20,0.10),(350,'Inlagd Sill',14.40,6,0.00),(350,'Jack\'s New England Clam Chowder',7.70,30,0.00),(350,'Teatime Chocolate Biscuits',7.30,12,0.10),(350,'Tourtiere',5.90,15,0.00),(351,'Filo Mix',5.60,15,0.10),(351,'Gorgonzola Telino',10.00,3,0.10),(352,'Flotemysost',17.20,2,0.00),(352,'Louisiana Fiery Hot Pepper Sauce',16.80,35,0.00),(352,'Teatime Chocolate Biscuits',7.30,40,0.00),(353,'Gumbar Gummibarchen',24.90,6,0.00),(354,'Boston Crab Meat',14.70,20,0.00),(355,'Gnocchi di nonna Alice',24.80,14,0.00),(356,'Filo Mix',5.60,20,0.00),(357,'Ikura',24.80,20,0.20),(357,'Tarte au sucre',39.40,35,0.00),(358,'Pate chinois',19.20,120,0.10),(358,'Tourtiere',5.90,6,0.20),(359,'Wimmers gute Semmelknodel',26.60,35,0.10),(360,'Louisiana Fiery Hot Pepper Sauce',16.80,28,0.10),(361,'Original Frankfurter grune Sosse',10.40,55,0.10),(362,'Gula Malacca',15.50,100,0.05),(362,'Rossle Sauerkraut',36.40,15,0.00),(363,'Chocolade',10.20,15,0.10),(363,'Outback Lager',12.00,25,0.10),(364,'Geitost',2.00,20,0.20),(364,'Pavlova',13.90,20,0.20),(364,'Spegesild',9.60,10,0.20),(365,'Flotemysost',17.20,30,0.00),(365,'Inlagd Sill',14.40,20,0.00),(365,'Perth Pasties',26.20,50,0.00),(365,'Sirop d\'erable',22.80,25,0.00),(366,'Maxilaku',16.00,21,0.15),(366,'Sir Rodney\'s Scones',8.00,40,0.15),(367,'Raclette Courdavault',44.00,36,0.00),(368,'Flotemysost',17.20,50,0.00),(368,'Gnocchi di nonna Alice',30.40,15,0.00),(368,'Gumbar Gummibarchen',24.90,30,0.00),(368,'Ipoh Coffee',36.80,20,0.00),(368,'Rossle Sauerkraut',36.40,30,0.00),(369,'Mozzarella di Giovanni',27.80,40,0.00),(369,'Spegesild',9.60,20,0.05),(369,'Uncle Bob\'s Organic Dried Pears',24.00,16,0.05),(370,'Rhonbrau Klosterbier',6.20,4,0.25),(370,'Scottish Longbreads',10.00,21,0.25),(371,'Nord-Ost Matjeshering',20.70,28,0.25),(371,'Pate chinois',19.20,60,0.25),(371,'Sir Rodney\'s Scones',8.00,40,0.25),(372,'Konbu',4.80,1,0.00),(372,'Tunnbrod',7.20,21,0.00),(373,'Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee',11.20,50,0.00),(373,'Teatime Chocolate Biscuits',7.30,21,0.00),(374,'Camembert Pierrot',27.20,20,0.00),(374,'Chef Anton\'s Cajun Seasoning',17.60,16,0.20),(374,'Gnocchi di nonna Alice',30.40,30,0.20),(374,'Ipoh Coffee',36.80,3,0.00),(375,'Boston Crab Meat',14.70,20,0.00),(375,'Guarana Fantastica',3.60,25,0.00),(375,'Rogede sild',7.60,30,0.10),(375,'Thuringer Rostbratwurst',99.00,18,0.10),(375,'Valkoinen suklaa',13.00,25,0.00),(378,'Ipoh Coffee',36.80,15,0.00),(378,'Nord-Ost Matjeshering',20.70,8,0.00),(379,'Chang',15.20,40,0.15),(379,'Gula Malacca',15.50,2,0.15),(379,'Pavlova',13.90,35,0.15),(380,'Carnarvon Tigers',50.00,30,0.00),(380,'Tunnbrod',7.20,15,0.00),(380,'Wimmers gute Semmelknodel',26.60,8,0.00),(381,'Gnocchi di nonna Alice',30.40,20,0.00),(381,'Uncle Bob\'s Organic Dried Pears',24.00,30,0.00),(382,'Guarana Fantastica',3.60,80,0.05),(382,'Manjimup Dried Apples',42.40,18,0.00),(383,'Flotemysost',17.20,12,0.00),(383,'Geitost',2.00,12,0.00);
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `ag715` ENABLE KEYS */;
UNLOCK TABLES;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE=@OLD_TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40101 SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE */;
/*!40014 SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS */;
/*!40014 SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40111 SET SQL_NOTES=@OLD_SQL_NOTES */;



-- Dump completed on 2019-06-02 11:20:01
```

below is also the HACKER script in case theres something I've overlooked.

```
CREATE TABLE order_detail AS (SELECT * FROM ORDER_DETAIL);

DELETE FROM order_detail
WHERE order_id = 267;

INSERT INTO order_detail VALUES(249,'Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

DELETE FROM ORDER_DETAIL;

INSERT INTO ORDER_DETAIL( SELECT * FROM order_detail);

INSERT INTO ORDER_DETAIL VALUES(251, 'Manjimup Dried Apples', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
INSERT INTO ORDER_DETAIL VALUES(250, 'Singaporean Hokkien Fried Mee', 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);

UPDATE ORDER_DETAIL
SET unit_price = unit_price + 1, quantity = quantity + 1
WHERE order_id = 248;

DELETE FROM order_detail;

DROP TABLE order_detail;

COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is if my backup file was modified properly, or if its incorrect and deletes the contents of a table ORDER_DETAIL when ran?

Yes, the backup script is deleting the `ORDER_DETAIL` table if it exist and then re-create the table again. That explains why the table is empty. See below:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ORDER_DETAIL`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client   = @@character_set_client */;
 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 ;
CREATE TABLE `ORDER_DETAIL` (
...
```

And then on the following script, the query inserted row to `ag715` table. Which explains why it has rows after running the script.

Try this, remove the line: `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ORDER_DETAIL;`

Then modify your `CREATE TABLE ORDER_DETAIL (` into:

```
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client   = @@character_set_client */;
SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ORDER_DETAIL` (
```

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose, creating a new table maybe is not what you are looking for! Please review incremental backup solutions like [Percona xtrabackup](https://github.com/percona/percona-xtrabackup).
I don't know why you do this, but maybe I should warn you, if you have some enterprise task, it is not a proper way to check the differences between data in the database layer! You should execute such processes at logic layer (with a proper programming language or scripting tools).